# How to return a tuple containing count of negatives, zero's, positives

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that returns a 3-tuple containing the number of negative values in nums, the number of zero values in nums and the number of positive values in nums.

This is my attempt but it seems not to accumulate the results.

```
def sign_counters(nums):
    """Returns a 3-tuple containing the number of negative values in nums, 
    the number of zero values in nums and the number of positive values in nums."""
    for num in nums:
        result1 = 0
        if num > 0:
            result1 += 1
        result2 = 0
        if num < 0:
            result2 += 1
        result3 = 0
        if num == 0:
            result3 += 1
    return result1, result2, result3

print(sign_counters([-1, 2, 0, -3, -1, 0]))
print(sign_counters([-1, -5, -3, -2]))
```

This should be the expected result with the test code (last two lines):

```
(3, 2, 1)
(4, 0, 0)
```

But my code comes up with this:

```
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every loop, it is resetting `result1`, `result2`, and `result3` to `0`. Here's better code:

```py
def sign_counters(nums):
    """Returns a 3-tuple containing the number of negative values in nums, 
    the number of zero values in nums and the number of positive values in nums."""
    result1 = result2 = result3 = 0
    for num in nums:
        if num > 0:
            result1 += 1
        if num < 0:
            result2 += 1
        if num == 0:
            result3 += 1
    return result1, result2, result3

print(sign_counters([-1, 2, 0, -3, -1, 0]))
print(sign_counters([-1, -5, -3, -2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out that `result1=0` of the loop.

```
def sign_counters(nums):
    result1 = 0
    result2 = 0
    result3 = 0
    for num in nums:
        if num > 0:
            result1 += 1
        
        if num < 0:
            result2 += 1
        
        if num == 0:
            result3 += 1
    return result1, result2, result3
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the result = 0 from the for loop.

If you put in inside the loop, you are reinitializing the value of result for every iteration.